# error importing seaborn into python3.6 on window10 64bit

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, seaborn

I am trying to import seaborn into python3.6 on window10 64bit but got an error. I have checked to confirm seaborn and other dependencies package are installed, and they are, but still I can't import seaborn into iPython. I keep getting the following error:

```
Python 3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5, Mar 21 2017, 18:41:36) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import seaborn as sns
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Emee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\seaborn\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .rcmod import *
  File "C:\Users\Emee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\seaborn\rcmod.py", line 8, in <module>
    from . import palettes, _orig_rc_params
  File "C:\Users\Emee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\seaborn\palettes.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .utils import desaturate, set_hls_values, get_color_cycle
  File "C:\Users\Emee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\seaborn\utils.py", line 7, in <module>
    from scipy import stats
  File "C:\Users\Emee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\__init__.py", line 348, in <module>
    from .stats import *
  File "C:\Users\Emee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py", line 175, in <module>
    import scipy.special as special
  File "C:\Users\Emee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\scipy\special\__init__.py", line 640, in <module>
    from ._ufuncs import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>>>
```

can someone please help me with this! I have tried checking it online, but came up noting... Thanks

Comment: Is the package present in the path seen in the trace?

Comment: Yes i think it is. I tried installing it again and it said already satisfied. Requirement already satisfied: seaborn in c:\users\emee\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages

Comment: can you check in the actual directory? i.e. `C:\Users\Emee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\seaborn`

Comment: I have checked, it is there.
17-Sep-17  08:28 PM    <DIR>          scipy
17-Sep-17  08:28 PM    <DIR>          scipy-0.19.1.dist-info
17-Sep-17  08:33 PM    <DIR>          seaborn
17-Sep-17  08:33 PM    <DIR>          seaborn-0.8.1-py3.6.egg-info

Comment: Your scipy install is broken. It's not a seaborn problem. Look at all those scipy + windows questions here on SO. I will always recommend anaconda, but everyone needs to decide that for himself.

Comment: @sascha do I need to uninstall scipy and reinstall it, or how can I fix it?

Comment: By reading some of the 1000 questions here in regards to scipy & windows including scipy's install docs (i recommend anaconda; one of the methods mentioned in the docs). My comment before is an educated guess after observing multiple SO questions.

Comment: thanks sascha, I was hoping I could find a way of making scipy work without downloading over 400mb worth file. but I will have to use the anaconda, since most other options are not working